# Как сделать переход на странице к нужному якорю при нажатии кнопки отправки формы?

Tags: php

Есть страница с формой. Скрипт обработчика этой формы
на этой же странице. Как можно сделать, чтобы при 
нажатии на кнопку отправки формы страница переходила
к определённому якорю внизу странице?

Метод GET не подходит, так как форма загружает файл.
Вниз страницы нужно перейти, так как там выдаётся
сообщение об успешной загрузке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если только средствами php, то делайте редирект на эту же страницу, передавая параметр об успешной обработке или ошибке и якорем.

А вообще, проскроллить с помощью JS - было бы гораздо проще.

Comment: Как можно с помощью яваскрипт опустить страницу к якорю, но без эффекта прокрутки?

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, если вас это успокоит, то некоторые специально делают редирект, для того, чтоб форма повторно не отрабатывала, если юзверь нажмет F5

Comment: Ну в моём случае редирект точно не подходит.

Comment: Если без всяких библиотек, то проскроллить можно так:

    function getDocumentHeight(){
        return (document.body.scrollHeight >  document.body.offsetHeight)?document.body.scrollHeight:document.body.offsetHeight;
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        this.scroll(0,getDocumentHeight());
    };

Comment: А куда тут вставить имя якоря? Или здесь как-то подругому?

Comment: Вам же надо прокрутить в самый низ страницы. Или якорь находить в какой-то другой позиции? Если второе, то вам надо в якоре задать id, например, "anchor" и написать следующий код:

    window.onload = function(){
        var anchorPos = document.getElementById('anchor').offsetTop;
        this.scroll(0,anchorPos);
    };

Comment: Да, нужен якорь. Спасибо.